# Table height of insert_table in python-pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

I use python-pptx and created a table with `insert_table` at the position of a placeholder.

```
ph = slide.placeholders[11]
table = ph.insert_table(rows=6,cols=1).table
```

Is it possible to make the table fit the height of the placeholder?
Alternatively, is it possible to define an overall table height for this table?

I know you can define a table height when using `add_table`. However, are there also solutions for `insert_table`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is you're on your own for that.

You'd want to divide the placeholder vertical size by the number of rows and set each row height to that.

Comment: [setattr(row, 'height', 250000) for row in current_table.rows]

current_table - table object
250000 - desired height